# Creating BusyBox Image without Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, ubuntu-14.04, busybox, rootfs

Any one please let me know how can I create busybox image from rootfs.

I referred this link
https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/baseimages/

I want to create busybox parent image and using this script file "https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/contrib/mkimage/busybox-static"

But I am not successful.

Please let me know how can I achieved.

I have tried below steps in the Ubuntu 14.04  machine

Installed  busybox in ubuntu machine

apt-get install busybox

then curl -LO https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moby/moby/a575b0b1384b2ba89b79cbd7e770fbeb616758b3/contrib/mkimage/busybox-static && chmod +x busybox-static

./busybox-static busybox

Then received  below error:

error: '/bin/busybox' appears to be a dynamic executable
  you should install your distribution "busybox-static" package instead

Comment: Can you use the [Docker Hub `busybox`](https://hub.docker.com/_/busybox/) instead of building your own?

Comment: I have tried same, i have started  busybox container and run busybox-static script. But no luck.

Comment: Finally, I got solution. As per this link  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/453740/installing-busybox-for-ubuntu I need to install apt-get install busybox-static package.